# code analysis report to include roslyn rules

Tags: code-analysis, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

When I run code analysis report in VS 2015, I am able to see all the warnings recommended by Microsoft. I have added custom analyzer created by using Roslyn, So when I re-ran the code analysis, I am not able to see custom Roslyn warnings in code analysis report.  Can some one help me on how to get these custom warnings get included in code analysis report along with Microsoft warnings which will be found in bin folder of solution after running code analysis on solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a custom analyzer you're using. 
If this is a custom implementation for Microsoft Code Analysis, go to settings of your project or solution and in the 'Code Analysis' section for the 'Run this rule set:' option select '' item from a drop-down and specify a custom ruleset file. If you need to use a standard Microsoft code analysis along with custom code analysis, use the  item.
If you're using a third-party analyzer (PVS-Studio for example or etc.), try to check its settings. Probably it displays warnings in a separate window.